# Como verifico se duas strings são anagramas uma da outra?

Tags: java, string

Preciso comprar duas strings e verificar se a segunda é um anagrama da primeira. Pensei em usar laços de repetição FOR. Creio que deva primeiramente verificar se ambas têm o mesmo tamanho, depois percorrê-las e ir verificando se cada letra da primeira existe também na segunda. Caso todas existam, uma é anagrama da outra. Só não sei como fazer isso...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ent = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s, r;
        int i, j;
        System.out.println("Digite a palavra/frase:");
        // crio as strings
        s = ent.nextLine();
        r = ent.nextLine();
        // verifico se têm o mesmo tamanho
        if (s.length()==r.length()) {
            // percorro ambas verificando se cada letra da 1ª existe na 2ª
            for (i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
                for (j=0; j<r.length(); j++) {
                // não sei continuar...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Uma forma alternativa de fazer é ordenar as letras de cada palavra em sequência alfabética e verificar se são iguais.

Comment: Eu notei que durante a aceitação você primeiro aceitou a minha resposta e depois a do Victor. Não sei se você sabe que a aceitação, ao contrário do voto, só pode ser feita para uma resposta em cada pergunta. E a aceitação fica na última que você clicar. Não sei se sua intenção foi realmente escolher a resposta do Victor, que é uma boa resposta, não teria problema algum em aceitá-la, ou escolher a minha. Não importa qual você escolhe, a decisão é sua, mas é importante entender o funcionamento da ferramenta e fazer uma escolha de acordo com sua vontade real.

Comment: @bigown Isso aconteceu porque eu vi primeiro a sua resposta e já aceitei, depois vi a do Victor e achei que ela se adequava mais ao estilo de programação que eu uso. A sua solução é boa também (se eu pudesse, manteria o voto nas duas, até porque são bem parecidas), mas utiliza modularização, que eu ainda não entendo muito bem nem sei usar direito. De qualquer forma, agradeço pela ajuda e por se preocupar em explicar sobre o funcionamento da ferramenta :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Penso em três formas de fazer isso.

A primeira forma é contar a frequência de cada caractere para cada `String` e então comparar as frequências.

A segunda forma é ordenar as letras de ambas as Strings e ver se o resultado coincide.

A terceira forma é usar funções do Java já prontas para isso:

```java
    s = ent.nextLine();
    r = ent.nextLine();
    char[] a = s.toCharArray();
    char[] b = r.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(a);
    Arrays.sort(b);
    if (Arrays.equals(a, b)) {
        System.out.println("Anagrama");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Não é anagrama");
    }
```

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 4):

Achei [essa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13692305/221800) que é o que você precisa:

```
public static boolean isAnagram(String s1, String s2) {
    //se as duas strings não tem o mesmo tamanho, não é anagrama
    if ( s1.length() != s2.length() ) {
        return false;
    }
    //tranfroma em arrays para poder ordenar
    char[] c1 = s1.toCharArray();
    char[] c2 = s2.toCharArray();
    //ordena para garantir a comparação simplificada
    Arrays.sort(c1);
    Arrays.sort(c2);
    //cria as novas strings baseadas nos arrays ordenados
    String sc1 = new String(c1);
    String sc2 = new String(c2);
    return sc1.equals(sc2);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yzoLus). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cticgqpr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Anagram.java).

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda!